# SpriteWalkthrough (Apple doc) translated to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sprite-kit, code-documentation

**In SpriteViewController**

in Obj-C, by Apple:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SKView *spriteView = (SKView *) self.view;
    spriteView.showsDrawCount = YES;
    spriteView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    spriteView.showsFPS = YES;
}
```

in Swift, by me:
super.viewDidLoad()

```
if let spriteView: SKView = self.view as? SKView {
    spriteView.showsDrawCount = true
    spriteView.showsNodeCount = true
    spriteView.showsFPS = true

    println("It works! :)");
} else {
    println("It doesn't work! :(")
}
```

I always get "It doesn't work! :(".

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

If you'd like to know more about the project in general, [see this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW1)

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your view is not an `SKView`. You can change this in the storyboard.

Comment: @0x141E - Thanks! I was being stupid. Sorry for your time. If you'd like a thumbs-up, post your comment as an answer. I'll be obliged to thumbs-up!